# criteria for aperiodicity and irreducibility of Markov Chains from Wikipedia page

Tags: definition, markov-chains

Let $P$ be the transition probability matrix of a Markov Chain, the Wikipedia page says that if $P^n>0$ for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then the chain is aperiodic and irreducible. I don't understand this theorem because on the right we have a scalar and on the left we have a matrix. If $0$ means the $0$ matrix wouldn't every Markov Chain fullfil this preoperty, simply by picking $n=1$? I hope somebody can explain me what I missunderstood here, this is an image of the relevant assertion

[image: criteria]

and also a link to the page [transition matrix german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbergangsmatrix#Anwendung_zur_Charakterisierung_diskreter_Markow-Ketten)

Comment: They likely are talking about a finite state Markov chain.  And they likely mean $P_{ij}^n>0$ for all $i,j$ in the state space.  That is, you can get from any state to any other state with $n$ steps.

Comment: ... including to itself